# Dropdown in React that goes with Onsen?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, onsen-ui

I've checked for quite a while & I see people suggesting to use the Onsen's 'popover' component but I'm not looking for something like that.

Just a responsive dropdown that goes well with Onsen & native apps.
Like maybe a dropdown with a smooth slide down effect when clicking on a list item.

Anyone found a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am not sure why you dislike the popover solution.

In my opinion probably the most elegant one would be just creating your own react component which can use the popover in its logic.

I'm not very into react right now, but I guess you want something like [react-selectize](http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/?category=simple)

```
var SimpleSelect = require("react-selectize").SimpleSelect;

var Menu = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var options = ["apple", "mango", "grapes", "melon", "strawberry"].map(function(fruit){
            return {label: fruit, value: fruit};
        });
        return <SimpleSelect options = {options} placeholder = "Select a fruit" transitionEnter = {true} transitionExit = {true}></SimpleSelect>;
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this on actual devices though, so I'm not sure how good it will be there. I guess there's only one way to find out.